# What is the exact relationship between variance and bias in regression?

Tags: regression, variance, bias

I know about the bias variance tradeoff such that with higher variance we have less bias and vice versa. But what is the relationship of this tradeoff? Is it just an exact inverse proportionality i.e $bias\propto 1/variance$?

Second part of my question is what factors cause high variance in our model? I know that multicolinearity and high dimensionality ($p>n$) increase the variance. Are there any other factors?